# Sqlalchemy get data from relationship

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have this models

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = Column(Text)
    author = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    to_topic = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('topics.id'))

    def __init__(self, content: str, author: int, to_topic: int) -> None:
        self.content = content
        self.author = author
        self.to_topic = to_topic

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(30))
    email = Column(String(40))
    password = Column(String(255))
    registred_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    last_logged_in = Column(DateTime)
    last_login_attempt = Column(DateTime)
    avatar = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('files.id'))
    role = Column(String(20))
    email_confirm = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    children_forum = relationship('Forum')
    children_topic = relationship('Topic')
    children_post = relationship('Post')
```

And I am trying to get query that will contain Post.content, Post.author.username but how do i do this in sessions?

I tried

```
 posts = db_session.query(Post, User).filter(
        Post.to_topic == topic_id).with_entities(Post.content, Post.author.username)
```

but that doesnt work because author is just integer (id) so I expect that I need somehow get the author object and post object in one query, but I dont know how. In sql that would be easy just 2 queries but here I dont know how it´s done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 query_results = db_session.query(Post, User).\
     join(User, Post.author == User.id).\
     filter(
         Post.to_topic == topic_id
     ).all()
```

I've never used with_entities, but I know this would give you a list of tuples where `query_results[0]` would be your `Post` instance, and `query_results[1]` would be your `User` instance.

EDIT: I believe you don't have to include the `Post.author == User.id` bit, but it's more legible if you're explicit with your joins.

Comment: You may also consider defining a backref, they're very helpful for these types of relationships. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html

Comment: I tried it and it works, but with entities gives me sql not list of tuples :(. But I leave that for optimization later now I need it to work and your solution does. And you dont have to give the join Post.author == User.id but I agreed it´s better with it. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad you got it resolved, and best of luck with the optimization. :)

Comment: I had a quick look at  backref because I really need some sleep now :) and I will try to implement it and see what changes, thanks